# How to setBody in Apex Class

Tags: apex

I need the value to be a variable and not "1646149510"
something like "value": variable1

```
    String body = '{'+
                   '"query": {' +
          '              "value": "1646149510"   ' +
          '        }' +
        '      }';
    
   req.setBody(body);
```

I tried replacing "1646149510" with variable1 but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

To replace “1646149510” with a variable in the given string, you can use string concatenation. Simply just do the following:

```
String variable1 = '1646149510';
String body = '{'+
'"query": {' +
'              "value": "' + 
variable1 + 
'"   ' +
'        }' +
'      }';

req.setBody(body);
```

If your varibale1 is a number use `String.valueOf` method as follow:

```
String variable1 = '1646149510';
String body = '{'+
'"query": {' +
'              "value": "' + 
String.valueOf(variable1) + 
'"   ' +
'        }' +
'      }';

req.setBody(body);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing how it is done in Java, but I actually need something for Salesforce Apex Class.

Comment: I update the answer due to your request.